# How do I convert my current form submission to an ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I've currently got the following set up:
I've got a form that submits an image, the action on that form calls to a new page 
"`test.php`"

On `test.php` a function is called via a server request check

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

The problem with this current set up is that I have to load the page `test.php`. I want the user to stay on the same page after submitting the form.

I'm gessing that to achieve this I have to use some sort of Ajax call. But I'm not quite sure where to start. If I make an ajax call to the page `test.php`, will it still proces the server request method?

The form sends some coordinates, and the file test.php crops an image via these coordinates, and saves it to the server.

```
<form action="/test.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
        <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
        <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
        <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
        <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
        <input type="submit" value="Crop Image" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" />
</form>
```

The coordinates are generated via another javascript function.

Any help or push in the right direction would help me out a lot.

Kind regards,

Comment: Do you have a preference between using plain javascript or jquery?

Comment: In your place I would use Uploadify.

Comment: Javascript or jquery are both fine, jquery framework is allready in place.

Comment: Uploadify seems a bit overkill since I allready have the functionality I want, but I want to run it via ajax in stead of going to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) as it will make your life a lot easier.

Then, you can send a request like this:

```
$.post('ajax/test.php', function(response) {
    $('#result').html(response);
});
```

This will send a POST request to ajax/test.php, then put the response output in a `DIV` with ID `result`.

Comment: Forgot to mention this in my previous post. The form sends some coordinates via hidden input fields. These coordinates are used to crop an image, this code is handled in test.php, the image is then saved to the server. This is the form that handles the input.

    <form action="test.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
    <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
    <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
    <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
    <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
    <input type="submit" value="Crop Image"btn-inverse" />
    </form>

Comment: Read the AJAX [documentation for $.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), you can send your parameters in line. `$.post('test.php',{this: that, foo: bar},...`

Answer (score 0):

The XMLHttpRequest object is used to exchange data with a server

But you can use ajax with jQuery to upload your images.

here is nice example :

[Ajax Image Upload](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html)

Demo :

[Ajax Image Upload Demo](http://demos.9lessons.info/ajaximageupload/)